# Difference Between EntitySet and EntityRef

Tags: linq-to-sql

I want to know what really is the difference between EntitySet and EntityRef in LINQ-to-SQL. As per what I a seem to have understood, EntitySet is one-many or many-many relation and EntityRef is one-one. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ relationships (The burning question)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367850/linq-relationships-the-burning-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

recently caught myself in the same doubts, so according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367850/linq-relationships-the-burning-question/1368018#1368018) you are right

Answer (score 2):

If the associated class is the many (child) side of a one-to-many relationship, the  many class will be stored in a collection of the  many classes, where the type of the collection is  EntitySet , and  T is the type of the many entity class. This collection will be a member variable of the  one  class.

If the associated class is the one  (parent) side of a one-to-many relationship, a reference to the  one  class will be stored in a variable of type EntityRef , where  T  is the type of the  one  class. This reference to the  one  class will be a member variable of the many class.

therefore, EntityRef & EntitySet act one-to-Many relationship,EntitySet act the many in parent and EntityRef act as One in Child.